# SQL case ceiling weird result

Tags: sql, sql-server

can someone help me understand why the case statement ([case test v1]) is behaving this way

```
select  
case when 0.510 <= 0.5 then '.5' end as [.5 test]
,case when 0.510 <= 0.75 then '.75' end as [.75 test]
,case when 0.510 <= 1 then '1' end as [1 test]
,CEILING(0.510 /.5)*.5 as [ceiling test]
,case 
    when 0.510 <= 0.5 then '.5'
    when 0.510 <= 0.75 then '.75'
    when 0.510 <= 1 then '1'
    else CEILING(0.510 /.5)*.5 
end as [case test v1]
,case 
    when 0.510 <= 0.5 then '.5'
    when 0.510 <= 0.75 then '.75'
    when 0.510 <= 1 then '1'
    --else CEILING(0.510 /.5)*.5 
end as [case test v2]
```

here are the results

[.5 test] = NULL 
[.75 test] = .75 
[1 test] = 1 
[ceiling test] = 1 
[case test v1] = 0.8 
[case test v2] = .75

how come [case test v1] is showing the result 0.8 ... when i comment out the else statement in it it works as expected and shows 0.75 (see [case test v2])

the result i would want via the case is to show data in these groups .5, .75, 1 (and then increment by .5), so 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5 etc

PS, value 0.510 is just an example, in reality the values in the column i would be using vary

thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `CEILING(0.510 /.5)*.5` returns a datatype of `numeric(9,1)`.

This has the highest datatype precedence so is used as the result of the expression and you get rounding when the string is implicitly cast to that.

Why are you using strings in the other branches? If you used `.75` SQL Server would see that it needed to reserve two places for scale as in the following (now returns `numeric(10,2)`).

```
select  
case 
    when 0.510 <= 0.5 then .5
    when 0.510 <= 0.75 then .75
    when 0.510 <= 1 then 1
    else CEILING(0.510 /.5)*.5 
end as [case test v1]
```

If there is some valid reason for using strings you need to explicitly cast the `numeric` branch to string - e.g. as below

```
select  
case 
    when 0.510 <= 0.5 then '.5'
    when 0.510 <= 0.75 then '.75'
    when 0.510 <= 1 then '1'
    else CAST(CEILING(0.510 /.5)*.5 AS VARCHAR(10))
end as [case test v1]
```

Comment: thank you so much! it worked ... there was no particular reason i was making the case a string, just didn't think it through :)